# How to Loop the List if Records using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have a List of items 500
here i need to take first 100 and then i need insert into Database .as so on...
but here when i insert first 100 into DB i don't need that records to be inserted into DB

By using LINQ

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Please edit it, having read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Sorry, do you want to insert those 100 items into the database or not?

Comment: *when i insert first 100 into DB i don't need that records to be inserted into DB* , didn't quite get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = myList.Count / 100;
int batchSize = 100;

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    InsertIntoDataBase(myList.Skip(j * batchSize).Take(batchSize));
}
```

Where `InsertIntoDataBase()` is some function you can implement to do the insert.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Skip and Take to do this.

```
var stuffToInsert = myList.Skip(100).Take(100);
```

`Skip` will move forward X objects, `Take` will enumerate upto (less if there is not enough data) Y objects. You can put Skip(0) for the first tranche of objects (because you are not needing to skip anything yet)

Comment: Without the Skip, or by saying Skip(0)